# Covering the small gap in window

Tags: html, css

So I've got a picture on the top of my website that I want to cover the top of the website ENTIRELY. But there seems to be a small gap as if it is marginalized, see:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt4Jm.png

HMTL:

```
<body>
<img id="bordi" src="taka2.png"/>
```

CSS:

```
#bordi {
height:100%;
width: 100%;
  }
```

I know it doesn't have a lot of code associated but it works fine apart from that gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this CSS:

```
body,html{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

there is `8px` margin in browser default you need to remove that.